# How do I fix my loops from taking the enter key as input.in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This question is similar to a question I had previously about loops taking my enter key as input.  For my class, I need to write a program that is a number-guessing game that whenever the user enters correctly, the loop ends.  But I run into the problem as the enter key being taken as input.  How can I stop this from occurring?  Here is my code I have so far.

```
  String secretNumber = "6";
  String guess = "";
  while(!guess.equals(secretNumber)) {
  System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
  guess = scan.next();
  if(guess == "6") {
  System.out.println("You Win!");
  }
  else if(guess == "5") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "4") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "3") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "2") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "1") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "7") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "8") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "9") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else if(guess == "10") {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
  else {
  System.out.println("You did not enter a number between 1 and 10");

  }
  }
  }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use == operator it doesn't compare the value of the string. So to check if a string's value equals to another, you must use string.equals(anotherString) method. In your case your code should be like :

```
String secretNumber = "6";
  String guess = "";
  while(!guess.equals(secretNumber)) {
  System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
  guess = scan.next();
  if(guess.equals("6")) {
  System.out.println("You Win!");
  }
  else if(guess.equals("5")) {
  System.out.println("Try again!");
  }
..........
```

**Also to refactor the code this version is more readable and simpler.**

```
 String secretNumber = "6";
          String guess = guess = scan.next();
          System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
          while(!guess.equals(secretNumber)) {
          if(guess.equals(secretNumber)) {
          System.out.println("You Win!");
break;
          }
           else{
          System.out.println("Try again!");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Strings are compared by equals second you need to learn how to reduce your code because  `while(!guess.equals(secretNumber))` will continue until 6 is entered so it will print anything inside it you we just print **Try Again**

```
public class GuessIt{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String secretNumber = "6";
            String guess = "";
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
            guess = scan.next();
            while(!guess.equals(secretNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Try again");
    
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
                guess = scan.next();
            }
    
            System.out.println("You guessed it");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I type in a number like 5 and whenever I press enter it goes to the else statement and says you did not enter a number between 1 and 10

Answer (score 0):

While your code is not the best way to implement a guessing game, I will play along if it helps you.

I don't entirely know what you mean by the enter key being taken as input. Are you typing a value into the terminal before you press enter?

```
String secretNum = 6;
String guess = "";
System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
while(!guess.equals(secretNum)) {
    guess = scan.next();
    if(Integer.parseInt(guess)>10 || Integer.parseInt(guess)<1) {
        System.out.println("Re-enter a number between one and ten");
    }
}
System.out.println("You guessed it!");
```